# Meteor JS execute JQuery after mongodb.find()

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

i'm using meteor js and now i have a problem.

I want to find some objects from my mongodb and after that i want to execute a jquery function.

The problem is that the find() method is called asynchron so the jquery function is called before the template got the data from the db.

So what can i do?

```
Template.dashboard.onRendered( function() {
//--- Slick Init ------
    $('.carousel').slick({
        infinite: false,
        dots: false,
        draggable: false,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
})

Template.dashboard.helpers({

    devices() {
        return Devices.find({})
    }
})
```

Comment: So... run your jQuery commands in a callback? You should show us your work.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, if you want to initialize a plugin when the subscription is done or when your `.find` returns data, then you should follow this pattern below.

```
Template.listing.onRendered(function () {
  var template = this;

  // Subscribe to data
  template.subscribe('listOfThings', () => {
    // Wait for the data to load using the callback to subscribe

    // Execute​ your collection .find()

    Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
      // Use Tracker.afterFlush to wait for the UI to re-render
      // then initialize your jquery component

      // Initialization code here
    });
  });
});
```

If the component that you are initializing does not depend on directly executing a `.find()` but instead depends on your template first running a helper, then you would follow a very similiar pattern.  The only difference is that you would not execute a `.find()` at all.

```
Template.listing.onRendered(function () {
  var template = this;

  // Subscribe to data
  template.subscribe('listOfThings', () => {
    // Wait for the data to load using the callback to subscribe

    Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
      // Use Tracker.afterFlush to wait for the UI to re-render
      // (this will ensure your ui has already executed its template helper),
      // then initialize your jquery component

      // Initialization code here
    });
  });
});
```

Obviously you would need to change the above code to use your specific template name and subscription name. This is only just to describe a specific pattern that you would follow.

I would also recommend that you review the [Blaze API manual](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) which provides a few other various subscription patterns such as this one.

Comment: var template = this; 

What is it for??

Comment: Just an attempt to be more verbose with the example showing that `.subscribe` is a prototype method of the `Template` object (which is the context of all the template callbacks...e.g. the `this` object). At the end of the day you can drop the `var` and just call `this.subscribe`.